# How to get the position of upper left corner of a rectangle shaped sprite (Unity Game Engine)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

How to get the position of upper left corner of a rectangle shaped sprite as you can see in the picture attached.

**Unity Game Engine**

[image: x]

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code so can others will get idea and give the solution.

Comment: What is that sprite attached to? What component is this? An `Image`, `RawImage`, `SpriteRenderer`, `MeshRenderer` .. ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is going to help you to follow [ask] [tour] [mcve]

Comment: You can calculate it having the size of the object and the origin position

Comment: @DouglasFerreira okay